# Sharpened Pinsker inequality for special case

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities, it.information-theory

Let $B(p)$ denote the Bernoulli distribution over $\{0,1\}$ and $B(p)^n$ the corresponding product distribution over $\{0,1\}^n$. For $n>1$ and $0<x<1$, define
$$P_n(x):=B(\frac12+\frac x2)^n$$
and
$$Q_n(x):=B(\frac12-\frac x2)^n.$$
I can show $ ||P_n(x)-Q_n(x)||_1 \le 2.1\sqrt{n}x$ using Pinsker's inequality.

**Conjecture:**
$$ ||P_n(x)-Q_n(x)||_1 \le \sqrt{3n}x.$$

Comment: An observation (which maybe you already know): let $S_n$ be the sum of the coordinates. A point has higher probability under $P_n$ if $S_n>n/2$, higher probability under $Q_n$ if $S_n<n/2$, and the same if $S_n=n/2$. So the total variation distance between $P_n$ and $Q_n$ is $P_n(S_n>n/2)-Q_n(S_n>n/2)$ (or, by symmetry, $2P_n(S_n>n/2)-1$).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at **[[Pinsker's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinsker's_inequality)]**, I am assuming that the left-hand side of the conjectured inequality is understood as the  the total variation norm of the signed measure $P_n(x) - Q_n(x)$, which equals 
\begin{equation}
 s(y):=s_n(y):=2\sum_{j=0}^m\binom nj\big[\big(\tfrac12 + y\big)^{n - j} \big(\tfrac12 - y\big)^j - \big(\tfrac12 - y\big)^{n - j} \big(\tfrac12 + y\big)^j\big], 
\end{equation}
where 
\begin{equation}
m:=\lfloor n/2\rfloor,\quad y:=x/2\in[0,1/2).  
\end{equation}
Using identities $(n-j)\binom nj=n\binom{n-1}j$ and $j\binom nj=n\binom{n-1}{j-1}$, we have 
\begin{equation}
 \tfrac1{2n}\,s'(y):=\sum_{j=0}^m\binom{n-1}j\big[\big(\tfrac12 + y\big)^{n - j-1} \big(\tfrac12 - y\big)^j + \big(\tfrac12 - y\big)^{n - j-1} \big(\tfrac12 + y\big)^j\big] 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} 
 -\sum_{j=1}^m\binom{n-1}{j-1}[\big(\tfrac12 + y\big)^{n - j} \big(\tfrac12 - y\big)^{j-1} + \big(\tfrac12 - y\big)^{n - j} \big(\tfrac12 + y\big)^{j-1}\big]. 
\end{equation}
Making in the second sum the substitution $j=k+1$ and then replacing there $k$ back by $j$, we have 
\begin{equation}
 \tfrac1{2n}\,s'(y)\Big/\binom{n-1}m=\big(\tfrac12 + y\big)^{n - m-1} \big(\tfrac12 - y\big)^m + \big(\tfrac12 - y\big)^{n - m-1} \big(\tfrac12 + y\big)^m
 =2^{2-n}(1-4y^2)^{n-m-1},  
\end{equation}
which is non-increasing in $y\in[0,1/2)$ for $n=1,2,\dots$. 
So, $s$ is concave.

Moreover, 
\begin{equation}
 s'_n(0)=n2^{3-n}\binom{n-1}{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\le 2A\sqrt n \tag{*}
\end{equation}
for some universal real constant $A>0$. It should be easy to see that one can take ($A=2$ for $n=1$ and) $A=\sqrt3$ for $n=2,3,\dots$.

Since $s(0)=0$ and $s$ is concave, it will then follow that for $n=2,3,\dots$
$$\|P_n(x) - Q_n(x)\|=s(y)\le2Ay\sqrt n=\sqrt{3n}\,x,$$
as desired (actually, for all $x\in[0,1]$).

**Addendum:** To verify $(*)$, let 
\begin{equation}
 r_n:=s'_n(0)/(2\sqrt n). 
\end{equation}
We need to show that $r_n\le\sqrt3$ for $n=2,3,\dots$. For $m=1,2,\dots$, 
\begin{equation}
 \frac{r_{2m+2}}{r_{2m}}=\sqrt{\frac{4m^2+4m+1}{4m^2+4m}}>1,
\end{equation}
so that $r_{2m}$ increases in $m$, and $r_{2m}\to2\sqrt{2/\pi}$ as $m\to\infty$. 
So, $r_{2m}<2\sqrt{2/\pi}<\sqrt3$ for all $m=1,2,\dots$. 
Similarly, in the "odd" case, for $m=2,3,\dots$ 
\begin{equation}
 \frac{r_{2m+3}}{r_{2m+1}}=\sqrt{1-\frac{6 m^3+11 m^2-8 m-4}{4(2m+1)(m^2-1)^2}}<1,
\end{equation}
so that $r_{2m+1}$ decreases in $m\ge2$. It remains to note that $(r_1,r_3,r_5)=(\sqrt4, \sqrt3, \sqrt{45/16})$, so that $r_1>r_3>r_5$.

Comment: I have added the addendum to verify that $s'_n(0)\le 2\sqrt{3n}$ for $n=2,3,\dots$.

Comment: Beautiful, @Iosif Pinelis!

Comment: I have simplified a bit the demonstration that $s$ is concave.